# Identify instance name that starts with RD* using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to find all the Azure instances that are beyond my threshold limit. My system detected the instances, now I want to pick up all the machines from the text and take action item. I only have PowerShell as an option to identify all the instances that starts with RD* in the below text.

```html
@{DescriptionEntryId=343578460; 
 Issue:
 </td><td>
 An xxxxxx has been triggered for 59 distinct instances of this xxxxxxx
 </td></tr><tr><td>Description:</td><td>setting up this to identify issue</td></tr><tr><td>Severity:</td><td>Warning</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><dl><dt>RDxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.393 and 6.054.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.722 and 6.813.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.481 and 5.909.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 14 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 1.412 and 6.588.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 3.375 and 6.24.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.382 and 6.863.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 14 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 0.418 and 11.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 3.059 and 6.667.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.255 and 7.5.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.545 and 5.291.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 14 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 1.691 and 5.6.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 14 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2 and 6.755.</dd><dt>RDxxxxxxxxxxx</dt><dd>The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes</div><div>
 View additional information about why the xxxx fired
 </div></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td><div><a 
 </div></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td><div><a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank">Suppress (Snooze) </a></div><div>
 </div></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td><div><a 
 </div></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></span>; RenderType=Html; Initials=; SubmittedByDisplayName=}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are displaying a HTML report of some kind and want to parse that using Powershell. For this solution you need to save the report in a .html file.

Lets assume you did that and saved the report to disk at `D:\Report.html`
Then you could do:

```
# read the report file as string
$htmlReport = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Report.html' -Raw

# create a Regular Expression object to capture the RD machines and their issues
$regex = [regex] '<dt>(?<Name>RD[^<]*)</dt><dd>(?<Issue>[^<]+)</dd>'
$matches = $regex.Match($htmlReport)
while ($matches.Success) {
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{ Name = $matches.Groups['Name'].Value; Issue = $matches.Groups['Issue'].Value })
    $matches = $matches.NextMatch()
}
```

Using the piece of report you gave, this will yield

```
Name           Issue                                                                                                                       
----           -----                                                                                                                       
RDxxxxxxxxx    The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.393 and 6.054.
RDxxxxxxxxx    The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.722 and 6.813.
RDxxxxxxxxxxxx The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.481 and 5.909.
RDxxxxxxxxxx   The threshold (2) was met for 14 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 1.412 and 6.588.
RDxxxxxxxxxxxx The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 3.375 and 6.24. 
RDxxxxxxxxxx   The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.382 and 6.863.
RDxxxxxxxxxxxx The threshold (2) was met for 14 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 0.418 and 11.   
RDxxxxxxxxxxxx The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 3.059 and 6.667.
RDxxxxxxxxxxxx The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.255 and 7.5.  
RDxxxxxxxxxxxx The threshold (2) was met for 15 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2.545 and 5.291.
RDxxxxxxxxxx   The threshold (2) was met for 14 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 1.691 and 5.6.  
RDxxxxxxxxxxxx The threshold (2) was met for 14 of 15 minutes. The data points during the evaluation window ranged between 2 and 6.755.
```

Comment: Thanks much, i will play around to get this in to my script, do you recommend any regular expression tool to make this easy for new bees like me with regex?

Comment: I personally like RegexBuddy, but it's not free. Online there are loads of regex testers like http://regexstorm.net/ Just google for it, you'll find one you like.